# Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I started to work with directives and everything went well so far. But right now I'm stuck. I get an error `Error: [$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: report.getContent()` and I don't see what kind of DOM node I'm referencing. Maybe I'm just dump!?

I've a scope function with will get a `report` instance:

```
$scope.showReport = function() {
            reportFactory.getLatestReport().then(function(report) {
                $scope.report = report;
            });
        };
```

My `report` object:

```
// report.js
return function(data) {
    return {
        content: new Content(data['content']),

        getContent: function() {
            return content;
        }
    }
};
```

The template which is in place will then call (?) a directive:

```
<div ng-show="report">
  <my-report></my-report>
</div>
```

myReport directive:

```
.directive('myReport', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'report/report'
        };
    })
```

The returned template contains a directive as well:

```
<my-report-content content="report.getContent()"></my-report-content>
```

MyReportContent directive:

```
.directive('myReportContent', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'report/content',
            scope: {
                content: '='
            }
        };
    })
```

Report template (`report/content`), but not working correctly since the error is thrown:

```
<div ng-if="content.hasFoo()">
  <div ng-include="'report/foo'"></div>
</div>

<div ng-if="!content.hasFoo()">
  <div ng-include="'report/bar'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you create a fiddle, it would be easier to see the error.

Comment: Good idea. Did that and during the fiddle process I found the root of my issue. The ```getContent()``` function in the ```report``` object returns ```content``` instead of ```this.content```. So it tried to get the ```content``` object of the template (```my-report-content```).

Answer (score 0):

Wrong:

```
// report.js
return function(data) {
  return {
      content: new Content(data['content']),

    getContent: function() {
      return content;
    }
  }
};
```

Right:

```
// report.js
return function(data) {
  return {
      content: new Content(data['content']),

    getContent: function() {
      return this.content;
    }
  }
};
```